# Agrupar hashes por valor em Ruby e manipulá-los

Tags: array, ruby, hash

Eu tenho esse array com hashes que simplifiquei para ficar menor. Meu objetivo é juntar pela `marca` dos `carros` para fazer um pequeno relatório mostrando o quanto aquela `marca` está lucrando baseado nas `compras`. Repare que a "marca1" repete 2 vezes e não quero que isso ocorra no relatório.

```
carros = [
  {
     modelo: 'modelo1',
     marca: 'marca1',
     compras: [{preco: 20000}, {preco: 30000}]
  },
  {
     modelo: 'modelo2',
     marca: 'marca1',
     compras: [{preco: 45000}, {preco: 60000}]
  },
  {
     modelo: 'modelo3',
     marca: 'marca2',
     compras: [{preco: 77000}, {preco: 23000}]
  }
]
```

Queria que o resultado final fosse algo do tipo:

```
Marca: marca1
Vendas realizadas: 4
Valor total: 155000
--------
Marca: marca2
Vendas realizadas: 2
Valor total: 100000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer essa manipulação é usando [each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) inicializando com um hash vazio. Então para cada nova marca encontrada inicializa um hash para a marca com contadores zerados e soma as compras e valor total de cada carro.

```
carros.each_with_object({}) do |carro, marcas|
  marca, compras = carro.values_at(:marca, :compras)
  marcas[marca] ||= {vendas: 0, valor_total: 0}
  marcas[marca][:vendas] += compras.size
  marcas[marca][:valor_total] += compras.inject(0) { |soma, compra| soma += compra[:preco] }
end
```

Resultado:

```
{
  "marca1" => {
    vendas: 4, 
    valor_total: 155000
  }, 
  "marca2" => {
     vendas: 2, 
     valor_total: 100000
  }
}
```

Comment: Consegui adaptar para o meu problema, obrigado.